# How to create special groups and give them special process

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, active-directory, groups

I have many admins on the network and I want to specify job for them for example I want to create group responsible for install and run yahoo messenger means I don't want to give them full admin rights in windows 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Guys no answer maybe I haven't explained well so I going to speak in another way.How can I give group full access to install and run programs for example I want to create group this group can install and run yahoo messenger, another group will install and run MSN messenger. I hope it's clear now,Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to configure a specific group-policy for the user-group.

I think that this will detail what you need to do.

[Application Deploying with Group Policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302430)

Remember that this only works with some types of applications (I think it's limited to .msi installers).